# Redis cache driver thrown exception in PHPUnit

Tags: caching, codeigniter, redis, phpunit

Anyone here had experience using Redis cache driver (CI v3.0.2) and testing it using PHPUnit (v4.8.16)?

I just tried it as described [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html) and it seems to work well in a browser, but when I go to my terminal and try to test it using PHPUnit, I got this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message 'Redis server went away' in /path/to/my-app/system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_redis.php on line 317

Call Stack:
   0.0002     247008   1. {main}() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
   0.0128    1116832   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:47
   0.0128    1117456   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:100
   0.1355    6531040   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:149
   0.1437    6885808   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:440
   0.1647    7612208   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:747
   0.1704    7615816   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:747
   0.1704    7616272   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:724
   0.1705    7617952   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:612
   0.1729    7937600  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:768
   0.1729    7938368  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:909
   0.1729    7938640  12. ControllersTest->testLoadController() /path/to/my-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:909
   0.1731    7941912  13. CI_Controller->__construct() /path/to/my-app/tests/core/ControllersTest.php:33
   0.1732    7943440  14. load_class() /path/to/my-app/system/core/Controller.php:75

RedisException: Redis server went away in /path/to/my-app/system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_redis.php on line 317
```

My environment:

```
$ redis-cli --version
redis-cli 3.0.5

$ php --version
PHP 5.6.14-1+deb.sury.org~wily+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
   with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
   with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

My 'application/config/redis.php' file:

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Redis Cache Configuration
 * @link https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html#redis-caching
 */

$config['socket_type'] = 'tcp';
// $config['socket']      = '/var/run/redis.sock';
$config['host']        = '127.0.0.1';
$config['password']    = null;
$config['port']        = 6379;
$config['timeout']     = 0;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got a solution from the CI Community forum, which is extending `__destruct()` method from `CI_Cache_Redis` class to catch the `RedisException`.

[Here the link](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-63397.html#pid324744) and here the code (edited a bit)

```php
// application/libraries/Cache/drivers/MY_Cache_redis.php
public function __destruct()
{
    try {
        $this->_redis->close();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Do nothing
        // log_message('info', $e);
    }
}
```